# 301 redirect in .htaccess - old URL includes ?page_id=

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I want to 301 redirect several URLs from an old WordPress installation within one subdirectory to a new WP installation within a different directory of the same domain. I.E.:

```
http://www.example.de/abc/?page_id=123
```

needs to go to:

```
http://www.example.de/xyz/newindividualpage/
```

I have tried several options I found here and elsewhere, but so far I was unable to get it to work, resp. adapt found code correctly to my needs. Obviously the `?page_id=` structure is where I am missing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to match the query string (ie. `page_id=123` part) you need a `RewriteCond` directive and the `QUERY_STRING` server variable (from mod_rewrite). Try something like the following in the `/abc/.htaccess` file (ie. in the subdirectory you want to redirect from):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=123
RewriteRule ^$ /xyz/newindividualpage/ [R=302,L]
```

(Change the `302` to `301` when you are sure it's working OK. `302` (temporary) redirects aren't cached by the browser, so makes testing easier.)

This redirects any URL within the `/abc` subdirectory that has a query string that *starts* `page_id=123` (as per your example).

---

Alternatively, if you prefer to only use the `.htaccess` file in the document root, then add the following to the *top* of the `.htaccess` file (at least before any other mod_rewrite directives) in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=123
RewriteRule ^abc/?$ /xyz/newindividualpage/ [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteEngine` directive only *needs* to appear once in the file. It can appear *anywhere* in the file, although it is more logical if it appears at the top. (It doesn't matter if it occurs more than once, it's just unnecessary.)

Comment: Thank you so much, w3dk! I had no idea that I have to put it into the subdirectory instead of the root directory!

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to go in the subdirectory, but it makes it a bit easier. (If it went in the root/parent .htaccess file you would need to change it slightly and ensure it doesn't conflict with existing mod_rewrite directives.)

Comment: w3dk, I am happy the solution works! But if there is a way to move it into the root directory I would eventually have the chance to completely delete the subdirectory once I do not need it anymore.

Comment: I've updated my answer with alternative code for the .htaccess file in the root directory.

Comment: w3dk - this it just perfect and made my day!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

You can also migrate your Wordpress posts using Wordpress Plugins wpclone by wp academy.

Comment: No worries, all is fine since late June of last year, with w3dk's solution. Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score -1):

You could also just install the excellent [WP Redirect plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) that will make for a quick fix.

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed. You need to provide context for the link that supplies an answer. Your linked reference can disappear tomorrow doing no one any good.

Comment: Isn't a plugin a bit overkill for such a redirect?

Comment: The old installation is too old for that plugin, Tom. Also, I want to get rid of the old installation and thus prefer the solution provided by w3dk.